# Is there a way to programmatically create routes in Sveltekit?

Tags: router, sveltekit

Sveltekit has a filesystem-based router, but I'm wondering if I can programmatically create routes?

The goal is to reproduce something like React-admin, a CRUD UI framework based on React, where you declare the resources you want to administrate along with the views that makes these admin pages, and have the programmatic code generates all the routes and plumbing yo connect to the backend.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out advanced routing paterns like rest parameters: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#optional-parameters

If that isn't enough, you can create a server hook to handle every requests individually:

> This function runs every time the SvelteKit server receives a request — whether that happens while the app is running, or during prerendering — and determines the response. It receives an event object representing the request and a function called resolve, which renders the route and generates a Response. This allows you to modify response headers or bodies, **or bypass SvelteKit entirely (for implementing routes programmatically, for example).**

`src/hooks.server.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  if (event.url.pathname.startsWith('/custom')) {
    return new Response('custom response');
  }
 
  const response = await resolve(event);
  return response;
}
```

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handle

Comment: Do you have examples of "implementing routes programmatically" ?

Comment: No, I don't have any. The code snippet I posted shows how you can handle a route like `/custom`. Whatever pattern to use is up to the programmer. So, it depends on what you want to accomplish. Maybe you could edit and add that to your question? I am not familiar with React Router, so I don't know what you would expect.

Comment: edited, I hope it's better now.